# Updating Code to work without FiletoOpen Application

Tags: excel, vba

Hello: How would I get the following code below to work without using the filetoOpen feature?  I would like to use the macro with the source workbook already open.  If you can help, please let me know.

```
Sub GetJEData()
    
    Dim filetoOpen As Variant, wb As Workbook, wsDest As Worksheet, pasteRow As Range
    
    filetoOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your file & Import Range", _
                                             FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls")
    If filetoOpen = False Then Exit Sub
    
    Set pasteRow = ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("Journal Entry").Rows(14) 'paste to this row
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(filetoOpen)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With wb.Worksheets("Journal Entry")
        DoCopy .Range("C18"), pasteRow.Columns("E"), True
        DoCopy .Range("H18"), pasteRow.Columns("L"), True
        DoCopy .Range("K18"), pasteRow.Columns("J"), True
        DoCopy .Range("S18"), pasteRow.Columns("AB"), True
        DoCopy .Range("O18"), pasteRow.Columns("Z"), True
    End With
    'next sheet (eg)
    With wb.Worksheets("Other sheet")
        DoCopy .Range("A16"), pasteRow.Columns("A"), True
        DoCopy .Range("B16"), pasteRow.Columns("B"), True
    End With
    
End Sub

'Copy column of cells starting at cell `srcStart`, to the last-occupied cell in that column,
'  and paste to `destCell`
'Optionally only copy cell values
Sub DoCopy(srcStart As Range, destCell As Range, Optional ValuesOnly As Boolean = False)
    Dim cLast As Range
    With srcStart.Worksheet
        Set cLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, srcStart.Column).End(xlUp) 'last cell in column
        If cLast.Row >= srcStart.Row Then  'check there's any data to copy
            If ValuesOnly Then 'only copying cell values?
                arr = .Range(srcStart, cLast).Value
                destCell.Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
            Else
                .Range(srcStart, cLast).Copy destCell
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(filetoOpen)` ---> `Set wb = Workbooks("yourfilename.xlsx")`?

Comment: A specific open workbook?  Or any open workbook apart from the one where the macro is running and which has a sheet named "Journal Entry"?

Comment: Based on what to identify "source workbook already open"?

Comment: I would only have two workbooks open: The source workbook to copy the info from and the destination workbook to copy the info to.  If the source workbook is already open, can it be incorporated into the code above?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it:

```vb
Sub GetJEData()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, wsDest As Worksheet, pasteRow As Range
    
    Set wb = GetSourceWorkbook("Journal Entry") 'find a source...
    If wb Is Nothing Then                       'got a source?
        MsgBox "No open workbook with sheet 'Journal Entry'"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'rest is the same....
    
End Sub

'Return a reference to the first visible workbook (in the current Excel instance)
'   which has a worksheet named `hasSheetName`
'Returns `Nothing` if not match was found
Function GetSourceWorkbook(hasSheetName As String) As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        'Ignore the workbook running this code, and any hidden workbooks 
        If wb.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name And Windows(wb.Name).Visible Then
            On Error Resume Next                 'ignore error if no matched sheet
            Set ws = wb.Worksheets(hasSheetName) 'test if sheet exists with name `hasSheetName`
            On Error GoTo 0                      'stop ignoring errors
            If Not ws Is Nothing Then            'got a match?
                Set GetSourceWorkbook = wb       'return `wb`
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next wb
End Function
```